# What is Tony Soprano's rank at the begining of the show?

Tags: character, the-sopranos

At the begining of *The Sopranos*, I don't understand exactly what is Tony Soprano's title in the crime organisation.

While DiMeo is in prison, Jackie Aprile is the acting Boss but he is treated for cancer at the hospital. Paulie, Pussy seem to be made men, *caporegimes* and Chris, a rookie soldier. So, is Tony also a *capo*? He looks higher ranked than Paulie and Pussy but younger thant them...

A subsidiary question is about the starting rank of Sylvio, who is often descibed as his *consigliere* (he obviously doesn't have the same rank than Paulie and Pussy) but as Tony is not the actual Boss, can he have a consigliere?

Comment: It's a criminal organisation with rules they made up themselves. Also: [With DiMeo in prison, Aprile became the official "street boss" of the family. ... With Jackie in and out of the hospital, and as such not able to fully run the family, Tony began to take on many of his duties, much to his Uncle Junior's chagrin.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Soprano)

Comment: Thanks @BCdotWEB, I've been reading some wiki articles, but I would like to have some hints or quotes from the show :-)

Comment: Note also that Tony's apparent position in the family was described differently in the pilot and in the second episode, which contributes to the confusion. See here:  [Was Tony the Boss of the family in the Sopranos pilot?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/14787/was-tony-the-boss-of-the-family-in-the-sopranos-pilot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tony Soprano was a capo at the beginning of the show. We can see it in the minute 1.29 of this scene (one of the greatest endings) how a police officer is reconstructing the mafia hierarchy.

Comment: Do you have any idea of Sylvio's rank maybe ?